# Recent raspivid segmented filenaming does nog work properly

Tags: pi-3b+, raspivid

I updated to pi3B+ and got the most recent raspivid.
In my old software I use

```
raspivid -sg 6000 -wr 40 -sn 4 -o REC_%04d.h264"
```

to produce a file named REC_0004.h264.

The new version produces a file named "REC_0010.h264" and 10 stands for the 10th day of the mounth.

When I use `-sg 6000 -wr 40 -sn 4 -o REC_%d` it produces a file named "REC_4.h264" which is correct. But I in my old software I need a file named "REC_0004.h264" (with three leading zeroes). How do I achieve that?

Comment: Looking at the source code only '%d' will use the segment now. If you want changes in there you could open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues